# Allow downloading unusual file types

Tags: media

I am trying to make `.dwg` and `.rfa` files downloadable on a Wordpress site. I've added the following code to allow them to be uploaded through the media browser:

```
function additional_mime_types($mime_types) {
  $mime_types['dwg'] = 'image/vnd.dwg';
  $mime_types['rfa'] = 'application/octet-stream';
  return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'additional_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

This works fine and I am able to upload the files but when I try to access them I get a 404 error. The file definitely exists.